# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql

I have a different server for my database.

When I connected to database with PDO, I used the IP address of database VM for host parameter:

```
$dbh = new pdo("mysql:host=192.168.56.103;port=3306;dbname=data",'root','root')
```

But I get connection refused (PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]'). I guess it couldn't find MySQL there. It could however, find the VM with that IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well then check if mysql is really not running:

```
sudo aptitude install nmap
```

And then:

```
sudo nmap -sS <ipofdbserverhere>
```

You can also install the tool on the mysql server, the the command would be:

```
sudo nmap -sS localhost
```

In both cases your answer should look like this.

```
[simmel]@[mars]$ sudo nmap -sS 172.16.1.41

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-04-08 15:09 CEST

Nmap scan report for 172.16.1.41
Host is up (0.010s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3306/tcp open  mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 33.17 seconds
```

If it shows you port 3306, it's indeed open and ready for connections.
If that is the case use mysql via command line from your computer.

```
mysql -u<USER> -p<PASSWORD> -h<ipofdbserverhere> <databasename>
```

The same message appears? Connection refused? Then your user has probably the wrong rights.

Another reason for this is when the mysql server is bound to a certain address, like 127.0.0.1.

To find out check the output from:

```
sudo netstat -tlpen
```

If mysql is not listening to `0.0.0.0:3306` but to `127.0.0.1:3306`, you only can connect from localhost.

To change that go to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and comment out the following line:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

The way to comment it out is to add a leading `#` character:

```
#bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Save the file and restart the mysql service

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Now you should be able to connect.

To change the port, enter, for example:

```
port = 8888
```

in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

Save the file and restart the mysql service:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: install it in the web server or database server?

Comment: I changed my answer for you :-)

Comment: the message is : not shown:999 closed port ,  PORT STATE SERVICE , 80 tcp open http . it didnt show 3306

Comment: Then mysql is not running at all. You need to start you mysql server ;-)

Comment: mysql is running :( Can i set port number for it?

Comment: Please post the output of the following command. My guess is, that it only listens to localhost mybe, or you are in safe mode somehow.

´sudo netstat -tlpn´

Comment: yeah your guess is right. in the web server just 127.0.1.1:53 and in the database server 127.0.0.1:3306 . so it didnt show 192.168.56.103:3306

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: Set bind-address correctly for a start, I'd say. Then also make sure that you allow connections from the other host.

Comment: correct unset the bind directive in my.cnf, sorry I was busy. I updated my answer, what to do exactly.

Comment: well then upvote the answer please :) press the arrow on the left "This answer is useful"

ah u did already, lol, sryyy ^^

Comment: yeah i did it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The error 2002 means that MySQL can't connect to local database server through the socket file (e.g. `/tmp/mysql.sock`).

To find out where is your socket file, run:

```
mysql_config --socket
```

then double check that your application uses the right Unix socket file or connect through the TCP/IP port instead.

Test the socket:

```
mysql --socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

If the Unix socket is wrong, you may symlink it, for example:

```
ln -vs /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

or correct your configuration file (e.g. `php.ini`).

To test the [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) connection directly from PHP, you may run:

```
php -r "new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;charset=utf8;dbname=dbname', 'root', 'root');"
```

Check also the configuration between Apache and CLI (command-line interface), as the configuration can be differ.

> It might be that the server is running, but you are trying to connect using a TCP/IP port, named pipe, or Unix socket file different from the one on which the server is listening. To correct that you need to invoke a client program (e.g. specifying `--port` option) to indicate the proper port number, or the proper named pipe or Unix socket file (e.g. `--socket` option).

See: [Troubleshooting Problems Connecting to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html)

---

Other utils/commands which can help to track the problem:

- `netstat -ln | grep mysql`
- `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep mysql`
- `php -i | grep mysql`
- Use XDebug with `xdebug.show_exception_trace=1` in your `xdebug.ini`
- On OS X try `sudo dtruss -fn mysqld`, on Linux debug with `strace`
- Check permissions on Unix socket: `stat $(mysql_config --socket)` and if you've enough free space (`df -h`).
- Restart your MySQL.
- Check [`net.core.somaxconn`](https://serverfault.com/q/408528/130437).