# Mysql ERROR 2002 (HY000)

Tags: mysql

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

i am unable to understand, how to resolve this ?

Comment: Search is your friend. Read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/606732/php-fatal-error-uncaught-exception-pdoexception-with-message-sqlstatehy000)

Answer (score 1):

Solutions for this:

```
#services mysql start
or 
#/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem, when i re-installed mysql-5.7 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
note) problem appeared after updating from Ubuntu 15 to Ubuntu 16.04, i also had to abandon my existing database. Still no help from Ubuntu.
after uninstallation  and

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql.*
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql
sudo dpkg --force-depends -P `dpkg -l |awk '/mysql/{print $2}'`
```

i reinstalled with:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-apt-config && sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Mysql ERROR 2002 (HY000) still remain
But following suggestions solve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get purge dbconfig-mysql
```

then

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

then finally

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin
```

**Re-Re-Updating the Ubuntu-kernel(2x) solved the problem.**